# Sonar: After upgrading java to 1.5 test success info widget disappears and sonar is not providing any failure/success report

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I have updated Java ecosystem to 1.5 in SonarQube 4.0 from update center. Since then I am not able to get the test failure/error/success percentage in `Unit Tests Coverage` widget. It was there before the update from 1.4.

Please help me in getting the same or downgrading back to Java ecosystem 1.4, as I am not able to figure out how to get the failure/error test cases after successful build because I am running `maven clean install` with `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` option.

Maven Command I am using is

`export MAVEN_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m && mvn clean install sonar:sonar -DCONFIG_PATH=<path to config of project> -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the maven command you run for SonarQube as well as the full log.

Comment: @DavidRACODON-SonarSource I have added the maven command, don't know how to share logs. Which log are you asking sonar or output of maven command?

Comment: As stated in the documentation, could you please run both mvn clean install and mvn sonar:sonar separately? See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven

Comment: Hi @DavidRACODON-SonarSource, thanks for the reply. I ran it in the documented way with no luck. I did see the document and I was using the alternate method as the first method was not giving the integration test coverage correctly. This command was working for me prior to upgrade. I think somehow the html got commented in the upgraded jar for Java ecosystem (just a wild guess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the update provided as Java ecosystem 1.5 for sonar. On 7th Jan 2014 I got the new upgrade for Java ecosystem as 2.0 and after upgrading the issue is resolved by it's own.

Thanks all for their time and effort.